# Is there any way to access nth document in collection in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
>db.collect.find()
{'name':'x'}
{'name':'y'}
{'name':'z'}
```

wanna access second document without giving any key,value to the function ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get nth item from a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31897103/get-nth-item-from-a-collection)

Comment: can be done by running a simple query `db.getCollection().find({}).skip(1).limit(1)`